# How to store global (url_for) URL's (and other global variables) and share across Flask application?

Tags: python, flask, redis, url-routing, jinja2

I have a number jinja templates; each share a number of common stylesheets and js resources. Within Flask, I use the url_for method to identify the URL for each.

Eg.

```
icomoonstyle = url_for('static', filename='css/icons/icomoon/styles.css')
bootstrapstyle = url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css')
corestyle = url_for('static',filename='css/core.min.css')
```

My question is; how do I share these variables within different routes without having to re-specify the above code under every decorator function?

Would I be right in saying that, anything global like this, should be stored within some kind of database or memcache (redis, mongo, etc.)? **OR** is there a best-practice way to safely store global variables like this within code elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these are static values, they don't belong in a database or cache; they should be defined in code.

You can make items available for all Jinja2 templates by putting them into `Environment.globals`, see [the docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#global-namespace).

Answer (score 2):

You can make them available directly to all of your templates by using [`app.context_processor`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.context_processor) to add values to the Jinja2 environment:

```
@app.context_processor
def provide_links():
    with app.app_context():
        return {
          "icomoonstyle": url_for('static', filename='css/icons/icomoon/styles.css'),
          "bootstrapstyle": url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css'),
          "corestyle": url_for('static',filename='css/core.min.css')
        }
```

Then *all* your Jinja templates will be able to use the variables defined in the returned dictionary:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ icomoonstyle }}">
```

Even better, you can put all of your styles under a single list:

```
return {"STYLES": [
    url_for('static', filename='css/icons/icomoon/styles.css'),
    url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css'),
    url_for('static',filename='css/core.min.css')
]}
```

and then loop over them (assuming you are only going to be using them in one place):

```
{% for style in STYLES %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ style }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Sean; thanks for this. In what way is this different to the solution provided by Daniel above?

Comment: The solution is the same in both cases - however, using `app.context_processor` is easier than trying to get access to the particular `Environment.globals` directly.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, the inclusion of the @app.context_processor directive in the __init__.py file causes Apache to throw the error:  RuntimeError: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed.

Comment: @Jordan - fixed now by explicitly pushing an app context to do the registration.